# Laptop for 3D Design and Modelling

Tags: laptop

I am looking to buy a laptop for 3D designing, surface modelling, and finite element analysis. I will be using softwares like Unigraphics, Rhino 3D, ANSYS, etc.

Requirements:

Processor: Intel Skylake i5 dual core or better

RAM: 8GB min. 16 GB preferable.

Memory: HDD: 1TB or better or 
                SSD: 256GB or better

Battery Life: At least 6 hours on designing usage.

OS: Any*

Screen Size isn't a constraint. All the basic functionalities of a modern laptop (wifi, usb, Bluetooth, etc.) are obvious.

As for cost, the cheaper the better. I do not wish to compromise on quality though.

*I do not mind using BootCamp on a MacBook if the MacBook fits the above criteria.

Comment: If the system lands in the gaming laptop or workstation laptop category, will that be ok?

Comment: Do you have an *absolute* price limit? e.g. less than $1000

Comment: Under $2000, since you have asked

Comment: In case you are still looking (or someone else stumbles across this question): It may be worth considering to get a laptop with a beasty CPU (such as a 6700HQ) and pair that with an external desktop GPU or to directly get one of those new laptops that feature Nvidia Pascal desktop GPUs.

Comment: 6 hour battery life is a big ask if you have some serious GPU load on a discrete graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

At the level of components you want I would recommend a gaming laptop. Being built with high performance components meant for gaming, it turns out that like games; 3D modeling can also leverage the same high performance GPUs and CPUs available for gaming laptops that complex 3D games do. As an added plus, gaming laptops typically ship with anti-ghosting linear switch keys that make for a great typing experience.

### I would recommend the [MSI GL62M 7REX-1067](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154623) ($1,100) at Newegg

[image: MSI GL62M 7REX-1067]

Key features on the laptop include a powerful **GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4 GB GDDR5** and an **Intel Core i7-7700HQ**.  These components are much more than adequate at driving the latest 3D modeling software. It also comes with a full **16GB of DDR4 RAM** which have faster RAM clock speeds than the usual DDR3 for faster application loading speed as well as a glorious **512 GB M.2 SATA SSD** with **sequential read and write speeds in the 2 GB/s range**. This laptop ships with MSI's signature linear switch laptop keyboard.

This laptop is overkill for your purposes but at a price tag of **$1,100** makes this laptop perfect for you and will hold you over for a very long time.

---

Additional notes:

I would like to mention that you're unlikely to find laptops that feature 6 hour battery life (even among power saving laptops) without compromising on the performance of the laptop. Intel, for example, purposely has it's U series processors which offer power savings at the trade off of cost.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Acer VN7-592G-77LB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834315130&ignorebbr=1)

```
GeForce GTX 960M 4 GB
Intel Core i7 6700HQ (2.60 GHz)
16 GB Memory 1 TB HDD 256 GB SSD
15.6" IPS FHD 1920 x 1080
15.35" x 10.35" x 0.90" 5.07 lbs.
Windows 10 Home 64-Bit
LED-backlit IPS display
```

Cannot find any stats on battery life however.

Another option would be:

[Lenovo IdeaPad Y700 80NV00Q9US](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834331907&ignorebbr=1)

GeForce GTX 960M 4 GB
Quad Core Intel Core i7 6700HQ (2.60 GHz)

16 GB DDR4 Memory 1 TB HDD 256 GB PCIE SSD

15.6" Full HD 1920 x 1080

External DVD+-R/RW

Again, no information on battery life found.

Comment: Note that while the CPUs of these systems are _very_ well indeed for a laptop, the GPUs are quite weak.